# i need to get solution of this question

Tags: plotting

2) Save f(x)=Sin(πx)/x  ,x∈[-3,3]
Find Maximum , Minimum and Inflection  points of f(x), then plot it showing on the graph maximum points in red color, the minimum in blue color ,the inflection in orange color.

Comment: Do you have any code showing your attempts?

Comment: I have tried but it was always wrong

Comment: Is this a question about the Mathematica software or just a math question?

Comment: about Mathematica software , i need plotting it

Comment: Look at the examples in the help for the Plot function. You can get to help by putting the cursor on the word Plot and hitting F1.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f, x];
f[x_] := Sin[\[Pi] x]/x;
p0 = Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}];
sol = x /. N@Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0 && -3 < x < 3, x, Reals];
PrependTo[sol, 0];(*solve does not find x=0 for some reason*)
hessian = D[f[x], {x, 2}];

result = First@Last@Reap@Do[
     lim = Chop@Limit[hessian, x -> sol[[n]]];

     Which[
      lim > 0, Sow[List@Row[{"Min at x = ", sol[[n]]}]],
      lim < 0, Sow[List@Row[{"Max at x = ", sol[[n]]}]],
      True, Sow[List@Row[{"saddle at x = ", sol[[n]]}]]
      ],
     {n, 1, Length@sol}
     ];

Grid[result, Frame -> All]

p1 = ListPlot[{#, Limit[f[x], x -> #]} & /@ sol, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p0, p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Solve` does not find the root at `x == 0` because the function and its derivative are undefined at zero and exist only in the limit. For the function this can be resolved by using `Sinc` rather than `Sin`. However, the derivative still requires a limit.

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. This makes sense. I had no time to look more at it, so just added the zero manually for now since the plot shows clearly the zero being a max.